# how to get the object of selected row in datagrid and assign their vakue to crossponding textbox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

[I create one table and data grid control and two Colum that is id and name and two textbox  id and name  .I want that when I click on my grid the selected value will display on their cross ponding textbox  such as id and name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEeYF.png)

I create one table and data grid control and two Colum that is id and name and two textbox  id and name  .I want that when I click on my grid the selected value will display on their cross ponding textbox  such as id and name.
I work on wpf application and visual studio 2015.  I create I button for show that show the value that is store in database and one button is update I want when I click on update button the selected row in d`[enter code here][2]`at grid is display in  and textbox name  text box in my form . I used entity framework .

I  done following code on show button

```
  var data = from p in db.gridtbls select new { ID = p.id, USERNAME = p.username };
  myDataGrid.ItemsSource = data.ToList();
```

and I used  following  coding on update button

```
 var  id = myDataGrid.SelectedValue;
 tbxname.Text = id.To String();
 tbxid.Text = id.ToString();
```

but  we  get  the  value in  textbox name is such as 
`{ ID=1, Name="aqib" }` is shown in textbox1 is the name  text box . I  want that only print in name textbox is "aqib"  and id  is "1".
how  we solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You create the anonums object:

```
new { ID = p.id, USERNAME = p.username };
```

You get object here(i think)

```
 var  id = myDataGrid.SelectedValue;
```

So... this object have 2 property ID and USERNAME

So..

Change this:

```
tbxname.Text = id.To String();
tbxid.Text = id.ToString();
```

to this:

```
tbxname.Text = id.USERNAME.ToString();
tbxid.Text = id.ID.ToString();
```

Comment: id.USERNAME     does not work  error show object does not contain a definition for username

Comment: Hey it is only example.   Use this id.ID.ToString(); IT will by like in Yours example